# How to show base image on minicart in magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-images, mini-cart

I want to show base image in minicart and checkout, Right now it is showing thumbnail images in magento2.1.7

I don't have any thumbnail images for my product so I need to point it as base image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Set Base Image on Minicart in Magento2,  you just have to add a etc/view.xml into your own theme (f.e. app/design/frontend/Package/yourtheme/etc/view.xml) ans add something like that:

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
    <width>72</width>
    <height>72</height>
</image>
```

To

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="image">
    <width>72</width>
    <height>72</height>
</image>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this topic we will do How to Change Product Image in Minicart

Step 1: Create di.xml file

Step 2: Create Image.php file

Product image in minicart will getten to  show by function **doGetItemData()** in `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem` class but this function is protected, so we cannot use plugin on it. Instead, it extends from `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem` and use function **getItemData()**

First We need to create registration and module file as per structure of magento 2 then follow below steps.

**Step 1: Create di.xml file**

Create **di.xml** file in `app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/etc/frontend`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
     <plugin name="Change_Product_Image_In_Minicart" type="[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart\Image" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**Step 2: Create Image.php file**

Create **Image.php** file in `app/code/[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart`

```
<?php

namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart;

class Image
{

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, $proceed, $item)
    {

        $result = $proceed($item);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($result['product_id']);

        /* thum url */ 
        $storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
        $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        if($product->getThumbnail()){
            $result['product_image']['src'] = $mediaUrl.$product->getThumbnail();
        }
        else{
            $result['product_image']['src'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhhh you saved my day thanks man upvoted

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 image in your product you need to set it as base, small and thumbnail.

**1. go to product edit page** 
[image]

**2. click on it and set this values**
[image]

**3. save product**

Comment: There are many products, So i need to go and edit each and every product, It is very time consuming.

Comment: Is is possible to change in code and point it.

Comment: You can try this

`foreach ($products as $product){

    $thumbnail = $product->getThumbnail();
    $imagePath  = '/catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

    if( $thumbnail == 'no_selection' ){
        echo 'FIXING ' . $imagePath . "\r\n";
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $imagePath, array( 'thumbnail' ), false, false );
        $product->save();
    }
}`